# Laravel Mixed Content was loaded over HTTPS

Tags: laravel, https

im working with laravel project.. and i have this problem:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxxxxx/admin/dashboard' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://xxxxxx/admin/dashboard/order_statics/September'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
# Disable Directory listing
Options -Indexes

# block files which needs to be hidden, specify .example extension of the file
<Files ~ "\.(env|config.js|md|gitignore|gitattributes|lock)$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

</IfModule>
```

i have this .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error on the client side, not the server. It's the browser saying that the main page was loaded over HTTPS, so any additional content that is loaded by the page must also go over HTTPS.

Find the code that is making the call to `http://xxxxxx/admin/dashboard/order_statics/September` (I assume it's in your javascript) and change it to either `https://xxxxxx/admin/dashboard/order_statics/September` or `//xxxxxx/admin/dashboard/order_statics/September`

Comment: eyy thaks you, but problem from Cloudflare SSL -_-

Comment: eyy thaks you, but problem from Cloudflare SSL -_-

Answer (score -1):

Solveed! Cloudflare problem... i Change flexible SSL to Full. and it work again!